# javascript difference (inside car function) this.color vs car.color1 vs car.prototype.color2

Tags: javascript

```
var car = function(){
this.color = 'blue';
}

car.color1 = 'white';
car.prototype.color2 = 'red';

var toyota = new car();

console.log(car.color);         // undefined
console.log(car.color1);        // white
console.log(car.color2);        // undefined

console.log(toyota.color);      // blue
console.log(toyota.color1);     // undefined
console.log(toyota.color2);     // red
```

Could you please explain why 3 of them have different answers before and after creating new object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`car` is a function:

```
var car = function(){
    this.color = 'blue';
};
```

Since functions are first-class objects you can set properties on them:

```
car.color1 = 'white';
```

This is somewhat equivalent to a static property in object oriented languages.

Functions can also behave as constructors (when you invoke them with the `new` operator). When they do, the instances they produce inherit from the constructor prototype. Property resolution looks at the instance and then proceeds to look down the prototype chain until it finds the property:

```
car.prototype.color2 = 'red'; // Property shared by instances of `car`
var toyota = new car(); // toyota is an instance of `car`
```

When you instantiated `car` the constructor was invoked and set the `color` property of the instance to `'blue'`.

So, for instances:

- When you access the `color` property it is found on the instance.
- When you access the `color1` property on the instance it doesn't exist (it's a static property of the constructor).
- When you access the `color2` property it is not found on the instance, but it is found on the prototype.

And for the function itself:

- When you access the `color` property it does not exist (because it only exists on instances)
- When you access the `color1` property it is found because you're checking the function object itself
- When you access the `color2` property it does not exist (because it only exists on the prototype from which instances inherit).